# How do I fire event globally in Angular (for currency conversion)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to have a currency conversion facility in an online website.
Assume you have an online shopping system, there you display all your products in USD. But there is a dropdown in the header/ navigation bar and when I change the currency type from USD to EUR all products displayed in USD should get changed into EUR. I can integrate my application with a currency conversion API which will convert USD values to EUR. But my question is, is there anyway for us to fire an event globally in Angular ? Can I do this with Angular pipes ? Has anybody done something similar ? Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks 
Sachini

Comment: In short: you can use a service provided in root to store and set the current currency, then a pipe which injects that service and does the conversion. You're gonna wanna call change detection from the pipe when the currency changes so trigger the update.

Comment: @IngoBürk thanks for the guidance. Will try this

Comment: Ingo is right, use a service. Make sure to use a ReplaySubject or BehaviourSubject in it that holds the currency. Once you update the value, you do it by emitting a new value into this subject and the whole app receives the updates.